# improperly terminted character error in haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I am writing a small piece of code for the average of a list, but it is not working properly and generating an error: "Improperly terminated character constant"

I am not able to solve this error. My code is:

```
average xs = sum xs 'div' length xs
```

[This is my small code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29aU2.png)

Comment: You need the "backtick" (grave accent, `), not the ' character.

Answer (score 4):

Use backticks  to make a function into an infix operator

```
average xs = sum xs `div` length xs
```

Comment: Off-topic a bit, but calculating a mean was the example that made arrows "click" for me. `average = sum &&& length >>> uncurry div`